# Python 2.6.5 defaultdict override __setitem__ infinite recursion

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to implement a dictionary that would do certain checks on keys that get inserted, for example please see below:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class CheckingDict(defaultdict):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CheckingDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if not super(CheckingDict, self).__missing__(key):
            raise ValueError("Key {key} is already present".format(key=key))
        else:
            return defaultdict.__setitem__(self, key, value)

a = CheckingDict(lambda: None)
a[1] = 1
```

The problem with the code above is that is gives me infinite recursion. So the question is why and how to do it correctly?

I don't want to use composition since to get all the functionality of a `defaultdict` I'd need to write significantly more code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's `__missing__` that's causing the problem, and note that:

1. There's no point defining `__init__` if it *only* calls the superclass; and
2. You aren't using `super` when you actually set the item.

A working implementation:

```
class CheckingDict(defaultdict):

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self:
            raise ValueError("Key {!r} is already present".format(key))
        super(CheckingDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)
```

---

So why does calling `__missing__` call `__setitem__`, leading to the recursion? That method *doesn't just tell you if the `key` is missing*; per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict.__missing__) (emphasis mine):

> If `default_factory` is not `None`, [`__missing__`] is called without arguments to
>   provide a default value for the given key, **this value is inserted in
>   the dictionary for the key**, and returned.

It is `__missing__` that's actually putting the default value into the dictionary if the key isn't already there, which means that it must call `__setitem__` to do so.